# InputHandlerException and DataHandlerException at install weblogic 12c

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have Java 1.8 JDK as JAVA_HOME and trying to install weblogic 12c in my local.

But cant open fmw*.jar file.

My log,

> C:>java -version java version 
>   "1.8.0_40" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
>
> C:>java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar
>   com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputHandlerException:
>   com.oracle.cie. common.dao.DataHandlerException: Unable to locate type
>   options-info in namespace  http://xmlns.oracle.com/oui/options
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getOptionsI
>   nfoDao(OptionsParser.java:478)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.parseOption
>   sDao(OptionsParser.java:183)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.(Opti
>   onsParser.java:130)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getInstance
>   (OptionsParser.java:117)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.OUIOptions.(OUIOption
>   s.java:53)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.(InputsImp
>   l.java:50)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.(InputsI
>   mpl.java:34)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.helpers.InputHandler.getInputs(I
>   nputHandler.java:29)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.processCommandLineArgs(Launc
>   her.java:2561)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:3197)
>           at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:3187)
>   Caused by: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: Unable to
>   locate type  options-info in namespace
>   http://xmlns.oracle.com/oui/options
>           at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.getUnmarshaller
>   (JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:219)

[image: My CMD SS]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Oracle Weblogic works with Oracle Java JDK 7 not JDK 8.
But you can succesfully install it with JDK 8.

Open cmd as administrator and then type this code:

```
<java jdk path>\bin>java -Duser.language=en -jar d:\jdev_suite_121300.jar
```

Change java jdk path with your original path location. Like this:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin>java -Duser.language=en -jar d:\jdev_suite_121300.jar

Answer (score 0):

You should change your PC's language settings at Control Panel. You cannot install weblogic with Turkish as your PC language. Especially, you should be careful to setting language to English as below screenshot shows.

[image]